# Scandinavian characters in tmux

Tags: tmux, iterm

```
# .tmux.conf
set -g status-utf8 on
setw -g utf8 on
```

Yet, still when I enter the scandinavian charaters `æ`, `ø` and `å` in the terminal window, I get the following output:

```
<00c3><00a6><00c3><00b8><00c3><00a5>
```

I'm using `Iterm2` as my terminal, and the characters are printed correctly outside of tmux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using *zsh*? I was able to get it to produce a result like that (inside and outside *tmux*) by setting LC_CTYPE to `en_US.US-ASCII` while actually sending UTF-8 (i.e. lying to *zsh* (and other locale-sensitive programs) about what character set to expect).

Check that LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE, and/or LANG have an appropriate values inside your *tmux* session; you probably want to use a consistent value that ends with `.UTF-8`. You can use `locale` to view the active values and `locale -a` to list the available values.

You may also need to reset the errant variable(s) in your *tmux* global and/or sessions environments (so that new sessions/windows/panes do not keep getting the bad values). You can inspect the *tmux* global environment with

```
tmux show-environment -g | grep -E 'LC|LANG'
```

Adjust its values with (e.g.) `tmux set-environment -g LANG "$your_value"`.

Each session can also override environment variables (for new windows and panes created in that session). You can inspect a session’s environment with

```
tmux show-environment -t "$session_name" | grep -E 'LC|LANG'
```

You can unset session environment values with (e.g.) `tmux set-environment -t "$session_name" -u LANG` (so that the global value will be used for new windows/panes), or adjust session values with `tmux set-environment -t "$session_name" LANG "$your_value"`.

Or, if you do not have any important sessions, you could just restart the *tmux* server with a set of known-good locale environment variable values.